# Math.Round rounds me

Tags: c#, .net

I understand if .NET rounds 2.5 to 2 using banker's rounding. But, how this could be:

```
decimal point;
point =51 * 70 / 100;    
Math.Round(point,0, MidPointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

rounds to 35?

How can I make all .5's round to upper integer even if it's odd?

Answer (score 10):

This second line in your snippet already gives you an integer result.

51, 70, 100 are of type `int`, therefore the operators for integer multiplication and division are chosen. The result of an integer multiplication or division is always of type integer again, and possible decimal places are truncated when dividing using `/` on integers.

The statement `point = 51 * 70 / 100;` is equivalent to

```
int tmp = 51 * 70;         // result is 3570
tmp = tmp / 100;           // result is 35 (!!!)
point = (decimal)tmp;      // point is 35m;
```

The solution is to change your code so that it uses `decimal` arithmetic:

```
point = 51m * 70m / 100m;  // point is 35.7m
```

Actually it is sufficient that *one* of the operands is of type `decimal`. This can either be achieved by using the suffix `m` (for monetary) or by using a type cast. The following sample will also give the desired result:

```
point = (decimal)51 * 70 / 100;
```

Comment: Strange, why is this necessary since OP is already using Decimal?

Comment: @Peter van Kekem: 51, 70, 100 are of type `int`, therefore the operators for integer multiplication and division are chosen. The result of an integer multiplication or division is always of type integer again, and possible decimal places are truncated when dividing using `/` on integers.

Comment: @Peter van Kekem: Because the calculation is done on the integers before it is assigned to the decimal.  It's all one line of code, but it's not all one operation.  First integers are multiplied resulting in an integer, then integers are divided resulting in an integer, then the result is saved to a decimal (which works fine because an integer can implicitly cast to a decimal without any problem).  The precision was lost before it got to the decimal.

Comment: and @David Thanks for the explanation. So casting to a Decimal will work as well, isn't it? (I was wondering what happens when this will happen with variables (entered by the user), when there is no way to add a 'm')

Comment: @Peter van Kekem: Casting should do the trick, sure.  The main thing to keep in mind is order of operations throughout all of the code.  (My code tends to have a more than average count of parentheses just to be explicit about such ordering.)

Answer (score 9):

You are doing integer division. Try this instead:

```
decimal point = 51m * 70m / 100m;
```